# Setting the right path in img.Image.FromFile();

Tags: c#, datagridview

Here is the code I wrote, in `img.Image.FromFile();` I have written the full path but it is needed to choose picture just from the folder Pics. I mean with the path I wrote when the selection of `DataGridView` is changed I see the pictures only on my own laptop.

```
 private void dataGridViewSearch_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (dataGridViewSearch.SelectedRows.Count == 0) return;
     dataGridViewSearch.Visible = false;

     if (dataGridViewSearch.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
     {
         buttonB.Visible = true;
         int n = dataGridViewSearch.CurrentRow.Index;
         string imgName = arr2[n].Pic;

         img = Image.FromFile("C:/Users/baghd/Summer2016/Desktop/1/Pics/" + imgName);
         //img = Image.FromFile("Pictures/" + imgName);

         pictureBox1.Image = img;
         pictureBox1.Visible = true;
     }
     else { }
        //C:/Users/baghd/Summer2016/Desktop/1/
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Statis class Enviorment to get desktop path on any computer:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "/1/Pics" + imgName;
```

also when you write your path you need to put @ in front of it because of slash

```
img = Image.FromFile(@"C:/Users/baghd/Summer2016/Desktop/1/Pics/" + imgName);
```

or

```
img = Image.FromFile("C://Users//baghd//Summer2016//Desktop//1//Pics//" + imgName);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, 
Sorry for answering so late.